# excel find the second match to an index match formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following formula:

```
=INDEX(A:A;MATCH(1;(B:B=H1)*(C:C=I1)*(NOT(ISBLANK(D:D))))*((ISBLANK(E:E))));0))
```

now i want to pull the second result from the A:A column that matches this formula and the conditions in the match function.
With this function, I only get  the ABCDE which is the first match(result), but there is another FGHI that also matches this formula. But it comes several cells below the first one.
My first match is ABCDE, and my second match is FGHI. I want to fetch the latter.
I have tried different ways, but I can't get around this one. 
Please help me in this regard.
thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are going to want to cut down the full column references to something that more closely approximates  the actual extents of your data. My preferred method is to incorporate `SMALL` against an `INDEX` array of row numbers that will replace the `MATCH` in your original formula.

`=INDEX(A$2:A$9999; SMALL(INDEX(ROW($1:$9998)+((B$2:B$9999<>H1)+(C$2:C$9999<>I1)+NOT(LEN(D$2:D$9999))+NOT(LEN(E$2:E$9999)))*1E+99;;); ROW(1:1)))`

I used a simple Find & Replace to change my comma list separators to semi-colons so I apologize if that needs minor editing to work on your system,

When transcribing for your own purposes, remember that `ROW($1:$9998)` is the *position within* A$2:A$9999 and not the actual row on the worksheet. `ROW(1:1)` is simply an incremental counter for `SMALL` that will provide *1, 2, 3, etc* as you fill down.

Comment: Thanks. However, since I had to trim down my formula in my question, here is my original formula which is a bit different. Since I use 'indirect' to fetch from another sheet. Here it is, but still it doesnt work:
=INDEX(INDIRECT("'"&file_list!$C$3&"'!$F$2:$F$999"); SMALL(INDEX(ROW($1:$998)+((INDIRECT("'"&file_list!$C$3&"'!$B$2:$B$999")<>parameters!$C$3)+(INDIRECT("'"&file_list!$C$3&"'!$i$2:$i$999")<>parameters!$A$2)+NOT(LEN(INDIRECT("'"&file_list!$C$3&"'!$d$2:$d$9999")))+NOT(LEN(INDIRECT("'"&file_list!$C$3&"'!$H$2:$H$999"))))*1E+99;;); ROW(1:1)))

By the way, my cell values are text string.

Comment: here is the final with minor corrections, but still no success:
=INDEX(INDIRECT("'"&file_list!$C$3&"'!$F$2:$F$999"); SMALL(INDEX(ROW(INDIRECT("'"&file_list!$C$3&"'!$2:$998"))+((INDIRECT("'"&file_list!$C$3&"'!$B$2:$B$999")<>parameters!$C$3)+(INDIRECT("'"&file_list!$C$3&"'!$i$2:$i$999")<>parameters!$A$2)+NOT(LEN(INDIRECT("'"&file_list!$C$3&"'!$d$2:$d$9999")))+NOT(LEN(INDIRECT("'"&file_list!$C$3&"'!$H$2:$H$999"))))*1E+99;;); ROW(1:1)))

Answer (score 3):

WOW! Thanks. Here is the ultimate working version. I had minor errors in my adaptation:

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT("'"&file_list!$C$3&"'!$F$2:$F$999"); SMALL(INDEX(ROW(INDIRECT("'"&file_list!$C$3&"'!$1:$998"))+((INDIRECT("'"&file_list!$C$3&"'!$B$2:$B$999")<>parameters!$C$3)+(INDIRECT("'"&file_list!$C$3&"'!$i$2:$i$999")<>parameters!$A$2)+NOT(LEN(INDIRECT("'"&file_list!$C$3&"'!$d$2:$d$999")))+(LEN(INDIRECT("'"&file_list!$C$3&"'!$H$2:$H$999"))))*1E+99;;); ROW(INDIRECT("'"&file_list!$C$3&"'!$2:$2"))))
```

You are a hero.

*Addendum by Jeeped:*

I'm nowhere near a hero until you understand how that actually works. I tried to put this in a comment but I was too long by half so I am using my editing privileges in the hope of clarification.

It's very important to understand how that combination of Excel native functions works if you hope to use the principals in the future. The first `ROW(INDIRECT("'"&file_list!$C$3&"'!$1:$998")` will work as written but would be better as`ROW($1:$998")`. This is just returning a number (i.e. matching row within `"'"&file_list!$C$3&"'!$F$2:$F$999"`. It does not matter where the number comes from. The conditions further into the formula determine whether it is a valid row number or not and those DO require the worksheet name from `file_list!$C$3` because their cell value is being examined.

In a similar manner `ROW(INDIRECT("'"&file_list!$C$3&"'!$2:$2"))` should be `ROW(2:2)` if you want the *second matching row within* `'"&file_list!$C$3&"'!$F$2:$F$999"`. This portion of the formula is just an increment for `SMALL`. If you put row(1:1) in a cell and fill down you will get *1, 2, 3, etc*. This transfers into the `SMALL` function as `SMALL(<a bunch of matching row numbers>, first)` then `SMALL(<a bunch of matching row numbers>, second)` then `SMALL(<a bunch of matching row numbers>, third)` etc. You are not trying to return *Sheet1!A1,Sheet1!A2,Sheet1!A3,etc*. Allk you want is *1, 2, 3, etc* to stuff into `SMALL` as the *k* parameter.

The Office.Microsoft.com Excel function reference are not always the most helpful place to go but here they are anyways.

[ROW function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/row-function-HP010069833.aspx)

[SMALL function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/small-function-HP010062539.aspx)